# How to display utf8 encoded font

Tags: opengl, glsl, freetype, freetype2

I want to display utf8 encoded font in my program but the output is only Question marks.

The following code works fine with English fonts but when i try other regional fonts i only get question Marks.

I am using Freetype to load fonts.

Please have a look at my code and let me know how i can use UTF8 Fonts in opengl.

This is my first project with handling fonts so any reference read or advice would be highly valuable to me.

Constructor for font object

```
Font::Font( const Shader& shader ) : Geometry() 
{
this->fontSize = 40;
this->shader = shader;  
this->Kerning = 3.0;
this->TextureHeight = 0.0;
this->TextureWidth = 0.0;
this->quadVAO = 0;

               stdstrTxt = "डेमो दृश्य"; // The utf8 encoded font

               glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 5, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);   
 }
```

Loading font as texture

```
void Font::Load(std::string font )
{// First clear the previously loaded Characters

this->Characters.clear();  // std::map for strorinf chars
// Then initialize and load the FreeType library
FT_Library ft;
if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) // All functions return a value different than 0 whenever an error occurred
    std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library" << std::endl;
// Load font as face
FT_Face face;

if (FT_New_Face(ft, font.c_str(), 0, &face))
    std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font" << std::endl;
// Set size to load glyphs as
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, fontSize);

FT_Select_Charmap(face, ft_encoding_unicode);
// Disable byte-alignment restriction
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);


// Then for the first 128 ASCII characters, pre-load/compile their characters and store them
for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++) 
{

    // Load character glyph 
    if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }


    // Get the Image width and height value
    this->TextureWidth = face->glyph->bitmap.width;
    this->TextureHeight = face->glyph->bitmap.rows;

    // Generate texture
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GL_RED,
        face->glyph->bitmap.width,
        face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
        0,
        GL_RED,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
    );
    // Set texture options
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Now store character for later use
    Character character = {
        texture,
        glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
        glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
        face->glyph->advance.x
    };
    Characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
// Destroy FreeType once we're finished
FT_Done_Face(face);
FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
}
```

Comment: "*for the first 256 ASCII characters,*" ASCII is a 7-bit encoding (often stored in 8-bits with a 0 high bit); so there are only 128 characters in ASCII. "*The utf8 encoded font*" That is not UTF-8 encoded. Or at least, it's not guaranteed to be. It is encoding in the implementation-defined narrow encoding scheme, which on *some compilers* is UTF-8.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas This is the code i am currently using to load first 128 chars of ACSII , would the same code work for asian languges like hindi.

Comment: @sam IIRC UNICODE is n*65536 characters so you need to use unicode font. There are no complete fonts for this out there to my knowledge but the most complete one is [GNU Unifont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont) but beware its raster not vector !!! beware the more complete font has ~16MByte !!! (at least my old version) smaller ones are just partial fonts

Comment: This is first llink I found that matches size... [unifont-12.1.02](http://unifoundry.com/pub/unifont/unifont-12.1.02/unifont-12.1.02.tar.gz) mine old archive was version 5.1 ...